# Function is undefined, cordova app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a function to call like this.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);}

function onDeviceReady() {

    function JustCall(phonenr)
    {
        window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
        action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_CALL,
        url: phonenr
        },
        function(){alert('success');},
        function(e){alert('error');}); 
    }

    JustCall("tel:5582001");

}
```

This straightforward call works but, when I use this it wont.

```
function onDeviceReady() {

function JustCall(phonenr)
{
    window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
    action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_CALL,
    url: phonenr
    },
    function(){alert('success');},
    function(e){alert('error');}); 
}

    $(document).on('click', '.view', function(event) {
        console.log("DEBUG - Trying to access view");
        loadRecord();
        $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#view-vendor', {
        transition: 'slidedown',
        changeHash: true,
        reverse: false
        });
    }); 

function loadRecord() { 

     $("#CallNow").attr("onclick", 'JustCall("tel:5582001")');
     $("#CallNow").attr("class", "ui-btn").trigger('create');

}


<a href="" id="CallNow"  class="ui-btn">Call</a>

}
```

JustCall is undefined. What I`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function JustCall is inner function of another onDeviceReady, so it is not visible from outside of function definition of onDeviceReady.